# TYPO3 10.4 session variables

Tags: session, typo3, typo3-10.x, usersession

how do I implement a session variable like

```php
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses','country',$country);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
...
$x = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses','country');
```

in TYPO3 10.4?

Comment: What did you try? With what error messages did you fail? Which documentation did you look at?

Comment: storeSessionData() is deprecated. 
I looked at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SessionStorageFramework/UserSessionManagement.html, but I can't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you just have to replace `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();` with `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();`